# Cannot print Hello World statement in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I am really new when it comes to C++, and have tried learning it.
So far I have installed the MINGW64 MYSYS2 thing for the gcc, gdb and g++ (compilers?). And have created my workspace.

Whenever I try to print the "Hello World" statement, it won't print it for some reason? I really have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;   
}
```

**Output:**

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file 

Starting build...
"C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\bsdwi\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\C C++\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.cpp" -o "C:\Users\bsdwi\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\C C++\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.exe"

Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Followed by this pop-up message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6qJm.png)

Has it got something to do with the Haskell thing? I am so new to Visual Studio Code and C++ so I'd really appreciate any help.
And apologies in advance if I have missed something out that you guys need in order to help me. Please let me know if you require more information.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you do what the pop-up said and open the `.json` file and make sure the `miDebuggerPath` is set so it can find `gdb.exe`? (easier, make sure the path to MinGW is set so `..\MinGW\bin` is in your path (environment settings top-window), and then you just open command prompt or PowerShell and type `gdb your.exe`) In your case that would be `"C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\mingw\bin"`